# How to establish secure connection between java application and database?

Tags: java, sql-server, database, sql-server-2005, http

In an interview, Interview asked me an question :

- The communication between our application and the remote database must be done with https (more secure).

How could you do it? I didn't find any clue for this question in google also.

How to establish secure connection between java application and database? Please help me.

Comment: Do you want to use HTTPS or do you want to use SSL? Using HTTPS would imply that you need to expose it as a webservice.

Comment: Is it a Java application or a Java*script* application?  As @BalusC has said, it's kind of strange to ask for HTTPS from a Java app, especially as a basic interview question.  But then you wouldn't really access the DB from Java*script* either, so that is a very odd question indeed.

Comment: If it were JS, it would make much less sense. If this was the *literal* question, then either the interviewer is dumb or he was just trying to testify your knowledge and opinions with regard to the "normal" practices.

Comment: He specifically told me to do the database connection using HTTPS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTTPS? If your client is using something proprietary with a web server acting as an intermediary to talk to the db server it would (one would hope) be transparent between your application the & web server; simply change from HTTP to HTTPS, ditto if you’re using SQL Server web service end-points (which you can make use HTTPS).

If perhaps you mean SSL then SQL server supports encrypted connections between client and server, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102493/secure-transfer-of-data-from-sql-server-to-sql-server-over-the-internet) question.

Answer (score 0):

Google for JDBC connection over SSL. See [here](http://www.razorsql.com/articles/mysql_ssl_jdbc.html) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully the person who asked the question wasn't seriously thinking about exposing a database to the wider Internet.  If they were, better not to accept that position.